# How to interact with sql server from monodroid through web service?

Tags: xamarin.android

I want to store data from monodroid application to sql server through web service.

monodroid  ==>  Web Service ==> Sql server

Actually i tried for asp.net with sql server via web service. its work fine for this appraoch. The data inserted into sql server.

asp.net  ==> Web Service ==> sql server.

but when i tried this similar way for monodroid,the data not yet stored in sql server database.

**Here is my code for Web service:**

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DINESH-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=remotedb;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand com;

    public Service1 () {

    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
}

    [WebMethod]
    public string insert(string name)
    {
        com = new SqlCommand("insert into dinesh values('" + name + "')", conn);
        conn.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

**Here is my code for monodroid**

```
public class Activity1 : Activity
{

    localhost.Service1 suresh = new localhost.Service1();
    string dinesh;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

        EditText e1=FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
        button.Click += delegate {

            dinesh = suresh.insert(e1.Text);
        };
    }
}
```

}

Help me,Is there anything i need to change in coding or i need to change any settings to access web service in monodroid?